# Dynamic DNS service for low qps but high deployment count

Tags: dns-hosting, dyndns, dynamic-dns, cellular

I deploy cellular modems that currently have sims with static ip addresses. For various reasons, we may move to providing sims without static ips.

The cellular modem supports DDNS (bluetree modem).

Since we will have a very low query per second rate (once an hour max), but a high deployment rate (hundreds to thousands), my needs are somewhat different than what you would find with many dynamic dns service customers. I think.

Should I look into running my own dns service (i have not the foggiest idea in what that involves), or is there a service provider geared towards low QPS, high deployment. Or will something like DynDNS be fine?

All devices will be deployed in the same country (Canada), and for quite a while only in western canada.

Comment: derp. will do! On other exchanges I am better, must have let this one slip for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up your own DDNS service isn't particularly difficult; the hardest part would be to make sure the clients can actually do the updates (as I'm guessing these devices you have don't support the proper dynamic DNS update protocol, but instead one of the many ad-hoc protocols the DDNS service vendors have dreamed up).  Also, if your devices are all network-localised together, running your own DNS infrastructure will give better performance than using an outside provider (who won't be as close, network-topologically).

If you need it done in a hurry, find someone who knows DNS service decently and give them a small packet of cash to set it up and write docs on how to maintain it.  If it's no hurry, get a copy of the O'Reilly BIND book and have at it.  If you can't get it done in a week of playing around, revert to plan A.

As far as using an existing DDNS provider, you'll automatically be reduced to using those which are compatible with the mechanism(s) available in your devices; beyond that, since you're dealing with large quantities of users they'll want money, and given that it's a commercial service you're running, you'll want service guarantees (more money).  It'll probably be a custom arrangement you're on, so get your negotiating shoes on.  My guess is that it'll probably cost as much in upfront time/money to get an agreement nailed down as it would to set it up yourself, and probably cost as much for ongoing service as it would to just run and maintain the setup yourself.

Comment: well put together answer. Who knows how it will end up, but I think I will pursue it in the fashion you suggest.